# Help me solve some paradoxes in this economic system

Tags: economy

**Normal economics**: Alan sells a grenade to Bob for \$100,  Bob uses it to blow up Charles. Alan gets $100 because Bob wanted the grenade. Bob gets the grenade because he wanted it. Alan is happy. Bob is happy. Charles says, "What about me?!" The economic system says, "You don't matter."

**Fictional economics**: The dictator wants to put in place a new form of money (or token), where people are rewarded for their contribution *to society overall*, not just to their trading partner.

- *Example one*: A factory produces useful things but also pollutes a river. A government inspector tots up the usefulness of the goods produced, another specialist inspector subtracts the value of the river lost. The factory is paid for the value of the goods minus the environmental damage. If they treat their waste, they see their bottom line go up.
- *Example two*: A bakery produces things that are good to eat and delightful smells. The government inspectors pay them for: the pleasure of the goods, the positive externality of making the whole street smell great, the social cohesion from the people working together and chatting. The inspectors subtract points for: the (Pigovian) harms caused by the sugary foods.

If this system sounds a bit silly and prone to corruption, good. That's a source of friction I want in the worldbuilding. There will be a complex, fallible, and annoying system of bureaucrats doing [cost accounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_accounting#Cost_Accounting_Methods), measuring noise pollution, worker-happiness, and other externalities. It would be feasible in real life for government statisticians to provide a monetary estimate of the harm caused by 1 packet of cigarettes; such statistical workers are more common and important in this fictional economy.

But there's a bigger problem I don't want: how do consumers interact with the bakery? I want the baker to get MORE compensation for being BETTER for society. BUT that means his treats should be more expensive. **This is the problem I'm trying to resolve: the state wants to incentivise the seller, but without disincentivising the buyer**. And ideally they should this using the same token the transaction is conducted in, not introducing a second one like a credit score.

So I guess the solution is to set up some sort of three-sided marketplace: seller-government-buyer. Or maybe just 100% state-owned enterprises. I feel like there's a clever solution I'm narrowly missing.

Two additional details that I see are relevant after reading some answers –

- The state has a monopoly on banking and payment systems. All payments are digital  and visible to the dictatorship.
- This will be a society with similar levels of computing technology to Terra in 2023, so "[it is possible throughout to review the process of production from beginning to end, and to judge all the time whether one or another mode of procedure yields more consumable goods](https://mises.org/library/economic-calculation-socialist-commonwealth/html/c/10)". In the Terra of 2023, Walmart and Amazon track 10⁵ or 10⁶  goods and their supply chains; the authoritarian planned economy will have technology like this available to them.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Where the extra compensation for the bakery should come from? I thought you answered that yourself in the question, by being overall good for society the bakery gets benefits from the government, either directly or e.g. as tax reduction or something similar.

Comment: Are you talking about a social credit score system? because that's what it sounds like, maybe take look at what communist china are doing and what the EU and WEF want to do .... @ooak he's asking for ideas for his economic system, so brainstorming rather than a specific question.

Comment: The normal orthodox mechanisms to implement what you want are called, wait for it, wait for it, taxes and subsidies. There is nothing unusual about taxing economic actors in order to cover the cost of the externalities they produce. (Ah, and a dictator, irrespective of how dictatorial they are, cannot put in place "a new form of money". All they can do is force the circulation of colorful tokens, for example Soviet rubles, but those tokens with forced circulation cannot be actual money. Because their circulation is forced, they cannot fulfill the functions of actual money.)

Comment: The essence of the question is: I want the socially-beneficial baker to be compensated extra. But that means the customer has more expensive donuts. So the customer is incentivised to use a socially-detrimental baker. Is there a way to resolve this contradiction?

Comment: Right, AlexP, not actual money, more a token-like system. Agreed.

Comment: *"The customer has more expensive donuts":* Not necessarily. The normal orthodox solution is for the state to pay a subsidy to those economic actors considered worthy. For example, the USA subsidizes the production of maize and sugar beet, because for some reason which I don't know (I'm not an American), the USA considers that unncessary production of maize and sugar beet is a good and holy thing. The EU subsidizes *all* agricultural production, because one thing which the EU wants to avoid at all costs is not being self-suficient in food. Etc.

Comment: @Pelinore maybe something like a credit-scoring systems that some companies like China's Tencent or America's Equifax could work here, but those companies use a separate number, a reputation score. I was trying to make it work using the same token as the transaction, something moneylike.

Comment: I don't see a contradiction, I think it's "only" a question of choosing the right amount of financial punishment. If, for example, choosing cheap and unhealthy ingredients saves 1\$ per pretzel but the "unhealthy ingredients fee/tax" costs 2\$ extra per pretzel, selecting the healthy ingredients is the financial sound choice.

Comment: We already do the baker thing now. the extra money the baker gets is called a tax credit, it is a reduction in the amount of taxes they have to pay. it is just done on the industry level instead of individual

Comment: @AlexP the idea is to prevent agricultural market fluctuation, grain market price fluctuation is one of the main causes of the great depression. (too many people growing grain when the price was high caused the bottom to fall out of the market, which lead to a food shortage and banking collapse" But to keep people from cheating they actually need to prove they could grow the grain, and the easiest way to do that is actually have them grow it, then not harvest it. Many have argued having the government buy the grain, use it as humanitarian aid, would be better but it would also cost more.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to ask how to incorporate negative externaliities into prices. This is a hard unsolved real-world problem. A reasonable solution to which is worth a lot.

Comment: Why not the solution the real world settled on? Insanely stupid bureaucracies that set up perverse incentives and then whine about the poor results, and even stupider constituents that then demand even more of what caused the problem in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Everyone has tokens

The inspector has tokens, the citizens have tokens, nobles have tokens. These tokens can be given to anyone who you feel should have a role in deciding what happens. When a group likes a business they donate these tokens to them to get licenses to use their products, and these tokens can be used to buy extra supplies and perks and privileges from the central government. A baker who is more expensive but offers a better service would get a lot of tokens and so be able to requisition whatever supplies were needed to make expensive goods.

To give an example, a bakery might normally provide one baked good per citizen once a week. A citizen who wants to have baked goods once a day might give them a token, getting the right to baked goods once a day for a month, and the business can use this token to ask the government for more supplies.

The baker has a unique power. They've gained enough prestige or support from the community to purchase a business license. This means they receive a certain amount of resources from the state to make their goods, and get a building and whatever other needed things for a business. So long as they are ranked as useful to the community they don't need to worry about basic supplies. If they prove very useful and get more tokens they get extra supplies.

The inspector has a range of unique powers. They have tokens they can award good businesses for following proper practices and helping the empire. They can also reduce the base number of tokens a business gets. If their token value falls too low, they can't support a business and the building will be allocated to someone else.

## Tokens quickly go out of circulation

Tokens are made of some cheap material, and each is stamped with a design showing off some important aspect of the empire and a serial number. Eventually they are all designed to go back to the empire and to be traded for rations or supplies or various social perks. There's no point hoarding them, and any attempt to make fakes is harshly punished, and easily detected because of the unique serial numbers.

## Tokens have many uses

They can be used by a business to purchase additional supplies, to get permission to expand their business, to get freedom from punishment for minor crimes, to get guards to protect a business, to purchase long term retirement goods for people. They're pretty valuable. People who want baked goods in addition to their normal rations might purchase a baked goods license so they get a snack from the bakery once a day for a period of time.

They have no inherent value. They're dependent on the government to redeem them for anything, and if hoarded they quickly become worthless. The average person can only use them to buy licenses to use a business a certain number of times a month, not buy anything tasty with them.

Comment: Yes, it's got to be some version of this. I'm not sure if the tokens should recirculate AT ALL, or be like a train ticket: a hole gets punched in it when it's used. Then cost could be computed independently for each transaction.

Comment: Since you've noted 2023 tech levels, you can make it all electronic so that every purchase can be tracked. Just have the tokens on a plastic card. You want to support a local business, you tap a console on the wall with your card and enter an amount. You can have both recirculating tokens and fixed ones, with some just being cards that when used can be stamped and become useless, some being your personal card, and some with some trade value. It's sometimes useful to have money recirculate if you want a fast moving market.

Answer (score 3):

### You Will Run into the Calculation Problem

How does a government inspector know the value of something without the bidding process of a market?  Values are not absolute, but differ for everyone.  They are not intrinsic to the product.  And they can change constantly as the needs and desires of the people change.

This has been the bane of central planners, who cannot plan the production of goods or set prices for them efficiently because the information regarding relative demand for goods is not available at all outside of a market process. The result is always shortages, gluts, and immense waste.

You are better off with a market based system for value, and a regulatory/tax system for externalities like pollution and a social safety net,  unless you are specifically writing a dystopia that shows how screwed up things would get under that alternative system of government bureaucrats determining what people should value, and by how much.

Phrasing this to match the question,  one of the pradoxes you have is a government inspector setting prices without knowing  what the people actually value. I don't have a good answer to that, other than to tolerate a lot of waste when things are priced too high and shortages when priced too low.

Are there other ways to get what you want?  Sure.   In economics, it's always helpful to think in terms of incentives.   How do you set up a set of incentives that rewards both the producer an consumer?  One way is through education.  If people really value responsible production practices,  they'll pay more for responsible goods.

Another way is through indirect punishment or reward.  For example,  let's say everyone gets a 'sustainability' score, and your government experts instead of assigning prices to products set a sustainabiity score.  When you buy a product,  its sustainability score gets added to the scores of the other products you bought, and averaged with the rest.

At tax time,  if your score is really good you get a rebate, and if it's bad you get taxed.  So now products that have good sustainability can be sold for more money, and both buyer and seller benefit from high sustainability products.  With higher taxes and rewards,  you can make the value of sustainability higher or lower,  but people still use the market system for pricing and coordination.

I wouldn't advocate an authoritarian system like this in the real world, but as a fictional device it might work and give you lots of story building ideas.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is that the government inspectors **charge** each company for its proportional share of the cost of cleaning up the negative externalities. The cleanup is done by government agencies, as **only** a government can do,with a profit-free service; much like the military or civil service in the USA: Nobody enlisted in the military or an employee of the government is paid exorbitantly, or gets any stock options or bonuses that will make them a millionaire. The highest ranked generals in the military, in charge of literally millions of personnel, only make about \$350K a year (plus free medical and a fair retirement package). (edit: I'm told in comments the legal limit is under \$200K, but that would just strengthen my argument here.) Even the President of the USA only makes \$400K a year, no bonuses.

The government can run a zero-profit organization because if they have any emergencies or unexpected expenses, they can just print money or borrow to cover it, and raise taxes next year to cover the shortfall. As we saw with Covid, the USA can just print a trillion dollars if they really need it in an emergency; and they did.

In addition, the government can offer "credits" for positive externalities, which they can use to offset up to maybe 15% of their negative externalities. Or even create an open market in which companies with more positive credits than they can use to sell their excess credits to companies being charged for negative externalities, to offset some of the negatives of the other companies. Like a stock market. If the price is right, the credits get sold.

Or maybe it can be social phenomenon; a company with credits can advertise the positive credits it has accumulated, and people can appreciate that. Like Subaru advertises how much money it has contributed to various charities (and it has). Subaru is not just the safest consumer car on the road, but the longest lasting consumer car (beating Honda that was once #1), and the most socially conscious consumer car company selling in America. They would not be spending $millions advertising this stuff if it did not sell cars! The same may go for positive externality credits (PECs).

But the government is not itself involved in paying money to companies; the market determines the price of both the credits and indirectly the cost of the cleanup efforts, because the government pays the market rates for the employees it needs to do the cleanup. It doesn't have to conscript anybody (much like the volunteer military -- If the pay and benefits are attractive enough, people will enlist, even if it means risking their lives).

As for the difference in cost if 15% of the cleanup effort is NOT paid for, that cost is charged as progressive taxes to the populace of the district in which the cleanup occurs; and enumerated separately. So they can see how much their dirty companies are costing them, and choose to not patronize them, to boycott them, or to vote to sanction them, or even vote to shut them down. And they will have a financial incentive to do that; the negative externalities created by that company are costing them actual money.

Give the power to the people. All they need is the right information, and a reason to consume that information. It doesn't have to always boil down to dollars and cents; don't underestimate the power of good will, and ill will.

Comment: just a small nit pick, during covid the government though about making a trillion dollar coin, but did NOT, they borrowed the money instead.

Comment: @John They "borrowed" it from the Federal Reserve that **printed it** it out of thin air. Or actually they don't print it anymore, it is just numbers they type into the computer that become a balance elsewhere. And you are right, the government can indeed just mint a trillion dollar coin or print a trillion dollar bill and wipe out their debt. Which tells you that the value of money is just an illusion, not based on any scarcity. Its value is entirely in the law: "This note is legal tender for all debts, public and private", which is enforced by the law, which is what makes money valuable.

Comment: currently in the USA military pay is capped at $199,300 per year. The pay scale shows higher for generals, but they they cannot get paid more then that limit by federal law.

Comment: @JamesCook I am unaware of that law. Do you have a URL?

Comment: @JamesCook I noted your comment in the post. It would just strengthen my argument, if true.

Comment: @amadeus 2015 NDAA. That law limits the pay of generals and admirals (officers in pay grades O7 and above) to the Executive Level II salary level for civilians.

Answer (score 2):

## Utilitarian Tax Brackets

When you buy something from a shop, some proportion of the price goes to the state and the rest goes to the seller. If you are American you know this well:

The sticker on the cheese wheel says 100 dollarydoos. When you buy it you take 123 from your pocket. The first 100 go to the seller and 23 go to the state.

In your society, goods that are deemed to aid society have lower sales tax. Goods that are a nuisance to society have a higher sales tax. This encourages the cheese factory to not pollute the river. That way they get a lower tax of 10% rather than 23%.

Now the wheel only costs 110 dollarydoos and everyone shops there. No one buys the cheese from the other factory down the road. The other factory makes the same cheese through a more wasteful method. Their cheese costs 123 dollarydoos but tastes the same. Eventually the other factory goes out of business.

The consumer gets the reward of a lower price. The seller gets the reward of more sales, when the competitor goes out of business.

There are a million billion ways a given good or service can be good or bad for society. I leave as homework how to boil it down to a numerical value.

Comment: That should work for story telling purposes. The government inspectors decide whether this cheese has a 23% or a 10% sales tax. They might do a good job, or not.

Comment: It takes 75 dolarydoos to make the wheel of cheese. So the maker get a profit of 25 when they sell one for 100, but to get the lower tax from the reduced pollution the cost to make the wheel of cheese goes up to 105 instead of 75. If he sells at 100 he loses 5 per sale instead of making 25, so his price goes up to 130 plus the 10 in tax for a total of 140. everyone goes to the other seller whos price is still 123.

Comment: Another scenario, one of two makers loans the local tax authority some money. in exchange they get the lower tax of 10 while their competitor is still paying a tax of 23.

Comment: @JamesCook In the first case neither factory would bother getting into the low bracket. PS: Thank you for using dollarydoos.

Comment: @JamesCook The second example is just plain ol' corruption. The asker says they are happy for the system to be open to corruption.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't.

Longer Answer:

You are describing a Planned economy. Without assuming what your political view is (but I've got a pretty good guess...) - these are/were common in Communist countries:

The State dictates what is good and will be produced, and the people will like it.

Doesn't work.

Also doesn't work when it's rebranded as ESG and pushed by certain NGOs - but that's a different story.

So my answer will be to describe the key reasons *why* it doesn't work, so that you can factor these into your story.

Reason 1: Law of unintended consequences.

Now, to be fair - this does also apply to a free market but due to other reasons, the free market is able to handle this better (most of the time).

Let's assume our Government inspector is an honest, well-meaning individual and sees something like a Liquor store. Clearly due to Drunk driving, Alcoholism, Domestic Abuse, Violencce etc. etc. Alcohol is bad and so we should restrict/ban it. Then you create a massive Black Market, make criminals out of the ordinary citizen and once already committing a crime, the inhibition to commit further crimes is lessened - so you get Prohibition era USA.

There's other instances you can look at where something that on the surface has no beneficial effects, without realizing the full consequences if you remove it.

The Free market generally is very good at reacting to those changes. The only instance where it's terrible is where there is no immediacy of effects (See lead pollution).

Reason 2: Market Demand

The Market is incredibly complex and what the value of something is, depends on the individuals. When we are dealing with population sized economies, there's generally enough of a consensus as to what the value of things are - such as what the Value of Gold is - but consider the old Indian adage of 'We can't eat Gold' - what is the value of a Bar of gold to a starving man, with no way of trading for a meal? To use a different, Shakespearean quote "A Horse! A Horse! My Kingdom for a Horse!"

A planned economy cannot factor in what the value of everything is for each individual - for a real life example of something seemingly that had no value, but was very lucrative for the creator - the Pet Rock.

If you asked someone what the value of a Rock is - they might say 'Free' or if we are talking Aggregate - a set dollar value per cubic metre - but $4 for a rock? That's something that the Free Market can do, but planned economy cannot.

In your scenario - think about the Pet Rock - how would an inspector evaluate such a product? how would they be able to factor in the *enjoyment* people get from such a product?

Reason 3: Human Nature and Human Perception.

This is related to the other 2 factors - but the simplest way to explain it, is to borrow the example from Konstantin Kissin's Oxford lecture:

"If you had a Button that in order for your child to grow up fit and healthy, you had to press every day and each time you pressed it, a tonne of CO2 was released into the Atmosphere, Every parent would be pressing that button till their fingers bled."

Humans are inherently interested first and foremost in self-preservation. That's why Heroes are considered extraordinary people - those who have the ability to override that interest for the sake of others.

That self-interest can manifest in different ways - for example, if a River that I never see, never swim in, never interact is polluted completely, but I save 20c a litre on Fuel - I'm fine with it being a Toxic dump.

It doesn't effect me. This is conversely where the Free Market is pretty bad - because it's very easy for each sector to externalize certain issues, in order to deliver a lower price to the consumer.

We see this often with businesses that have a particular 'cause' that they are passionate about - but fail to sell to the end-consumer because the product is either over-priced or inferior. Often they need the fiat of Government Legislation to be 'competitive' but even then, they are often not.

Humans are funny creatures and we are all different and there is no way that any top-down system can account for these differences in preference, taste and all the factors that drive demand in the way that a free market can.

Comment: The idea in 'Reason 2' of altering price in response to individual need would be an interesting thing to explore in a fictional economy. Something like "auctions for everything", so that food costs more if you're hungry. It's very different from the economics we're used to where things have a standard list price and individual desire is not factored in.

Comment: @wokopa Well, that's not kinda true - even things with a 'standard price' are subject to market forces. If you go to a butcher to buy a steak and it's $20 more expensive than the butcher down the road, who do you buy from? The Standard price is in reality the result of a Meta-Auction from thousands or millions of transactions.

Comment: You are confusing use-value with exchange-value.

Comment: I read your comment again. Apart from confusing price with value (a basic-economics confusion), the core of your objection seems to be that planners do not factor in demand. This is obviously wrong. Why would planners not factor in demand? It's the main thing they factor in.

Comment: @wokopa - I disagree that I'm confusing Price with Value, I'm highlighting why they are different *and that a centrally planned economy cannot account for the difference in a way that the free market can*. As for the latter - I mean let's look at the US vs every centrally planned economy - the variety of choice in the US is massive *because it's predicated on Demand* - whereas a Centrally planned economy says 'People need, soap, we have produced soap, therefore no more demand' - whereas the US says we have smelly soap, sensitive soap, antibacterial soap, novelty soap, naughty soap etc. etc.

Comment: Ok, well the planners in my story would respond to demand. Why wouldn't they? Even the Wikipedia pages on Gosplan and Cybersyn discuss responding to demand.

Comment: @wokopa - Because you can't evaluate demand for something people don't know they want. And sure, Gosplan *talks* about responding to demand, but the *reality* is/was that they couldn't. Again - compare the amount of choice for any given product in the US market in the mid 80s with the USSR.

Comment: What is an example of "something people don't know they want"?

Comment: As for "Gosplan couldn't....", I've specified that this is using computation 10¹²× what was available to them. The sort of computational power that is available to today's large centrally-planned economies like Amazon. I've talked to people whose job it is to centrally predict demand for Amazon, I assure you they're doing it every day based on consumer behaviour.

Comment: @wokopa "If I asked people what they wanted, they would have said a faster Horse" - Henry Ford (attributed) - I mean, social Media and TikTok is probably the most recent example - we already had video sharing (YouTube) - people didn't know they wanted a short-form video platform - yet here we are. Amazon is a bad example - because it's *mostly* a free market - an individual with a cool new product that no one has heard of can sign up to Amazon to sell it. Without the approval of your Agent. That is the difference. It's not a question of computational power.

Comment: Oh are you talking about innovation? Yeah that's quite a different thing to day-to-day supply-and-demand planning. A few percent of the budget has to be given to R&D so we can get all these things like communications satellites, the Internet, programmable computers, etc. that came out of public R&D budget. I hadn't mentioned that yet because we were talking about something else.

Comment: @wokopa "today's large centrally-planned economies like Amazon" Rubbish. https://www.cato.org/commentary/no-walmart-not-evidence-centrally-planned-economies-work https://fee.org/articles/socialist-mag-mega-companies-like-amazon-and-walmart-show-that-central-planning-would-finally-work

Comment: @wokopa - See, I'm not opposed to Government R&D - but things like the Internet - sure  ARPANet was a precursor... but almost all of the things that we benefit from and *demand* were created by individuals. Centrally planned economies cannot and more importantly *have never* introduced innovation and demand in anything remotely comparable to Free Market Economies. I *again* have to say *look at the reality of every single time it was implemented*.

Comment: I suppose both have their place. There are cases when you want to completely ignore consumer demand (like your Henry Ford example), and times when you want to steer the system based on demand like Cybersyn or Gosplan. The first for innovation, the second for day-to-day stuff.

Comment: @wokopa "the second for day-to-day stuff" Absolutely not. There's a reason the USSR had to imprison its citizens to stop them from emigrating.

Answer (score 0):

I see a clear problem with this system. The inspector. How can an inspector know the intrinsic value of an action? How can they know what people value or what benefits society? Sure, you can make generalizations, but everyone has a slightly different value system. Some people appreciate the smell of a bakery more than others.

The solution is also quite strait forward. What if the consumer dictated what is 'beneficial' and what isn't? It would resolve the inspector problem because it then becomes a law of averages. If a factory pollutes as river, the people who suffer, like fishermen, can lean against the factory, and fill the role the inspector would have had.

If the people like the smell of fresh bread? Then they lean towards the bakery and they get a compensation of some kind. Maybe some sort of point system where when have a given number of points to use towards and against industries/factories/buildings/bakeries...

Of course you'd need to adapt it towards your world, and altering peoples perceptions is a clearcut way to exploit and corrupt the system, getting them to change the way they value certain things. But it's up to you how you execute this, be it some digital-cashless-society style or some kind of physical token.

Comment: This makes no attempt to answer the question, which is: how can you reward the seller without jacking up prices for the consumer

Comment: "What if the consumer dictated what is 'beneficial' and what isn't?" – I addressed this in the first paragraph of the post

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have a rough answer now using graph theory. In graph theory there are **1)** people, and **2)** interactions between people. Or you could say entity 1 is bank accounts, and entity 2 is transfers.

[image]

My problem was I was thinking of the state intervening in the bank accounts, when I should have been thinking about intervening in the transfers.

Benny Buyer goes into Frank's farmers' market. The farmers' market has positive externalities: it provides [social cohesion which is valuable](https://ourworldindata.org/social-networks-innovation-and-productivity) and supports farmers who help build the soil and protect biodiversity. Now Benny makes a payment of 5 units to Frank, at Frank's terminal, by scanning the product code, or selecting it from a menu or whatever. This payment, remember, goes through the monopolistic state payment system. Instead of Benny's balance going -5 and Frank's going +5 like you'd expect, Benny's goes -4 and Frank's goes +6 to account for the positive externalities. Where does the extra money come from? Magic/thin air/nowhere. It's just coined by the system during the transaction.

And conversely, if it's a socially harmful or polluting business, the buyer will see their balance fall by 6, the seller only get 4 (when a product of value 5 is paid for).

These are non-zero-sum transactions to represent the non-zero-sum value of the activities.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special fund made with money from special lump-sum tax, which was introduced specifically for this purpose. Due to being a lump sum tax it doesn't change incentives of buyers. And then the State uses this special fund to give subsidies for producing "good" goods, while also imposing price limits for said goods which is lower than prices of "bad" goods.

Answer (score -1):

**You're thinking about the wrong end of economics**

This has nothing to do with money or how much a customer should spend for a product or service.

This entirely depends on the government incentivizing business based on what the government thinks is valuable. Governments do that in several ways:

- tax breaks,
- grants and subsidies,
- favored trading status with the government (government buys from said business first...),
- legal intervention (government looks the other way when owners commit a crime...),
- political influence (owner is given a cabinet seat or other high-level job...),

And a whole lot more. The real question isn't whether or not you can use fiat currency to facilitate massive bureaucracy and the inevitable corruption that comes with it (call it money, or dollars, or marks, or tokens, or any other word, that's just an aesthetic), the real question is, *what are the goals of the government?*

In a best-of-all-worlds situation, the government wants to be perceived as advancing the cause of the little guy, of making the economy better! It does not want to be perceived as incompetent (at least not blatantly so) and it definitely doesn't want to be caught playing favorites! So, the confusion you're looking for has much more to do with the non-economic goals of the government than it does the basic supply-and-demand trading practices of your average business.

**So, what does it mean for a business to be rewarded for good behavior?**

I'm a fan of your basic example: a business is producing a product and polluting a river. One inspector finds the economic value of the product to be X and another finds the ecological cost of the pollution to be Y. If X>Y the business is rewarded. What's missing are a few details.

*A company is economically beneficial when...*

1. It can sustain a high number of employees.
2. The average period of employment is measured in decades.
3. The average wage is no less than 5% below the national average.
4. The company demonstrates annual growth exceeding 5%.
5. The company demonstrates local community involvement (charities, grants, etc.)
6. The company demonstrates regional involvement (political support, cooperative trade agreements, etc.)
7. The company demonstrates national involvement (political support, contributions to defense, etc.)

Note that I've listed a lot of *positive* issues. Negative issues that might be perceived as beneficial might be helping out a national political leader who was caught golfing with Satan in a way that kept the issue out of the press or encouraging your 20-something married child to "take one for the team" by hosting a quiet evening alone with a foreign dignitary because a political leader asked for a favor. You can get *really nefarious* with this and yet produce exactly the kinds of "beneficial" conditions (you rub my back, I'll rub yours...) that would lead to looking the other way when it comes to that river.

*A company is economically detrimental when...*

1. The company has a high number of public complaints.
2. The company (directly or indirectly) is associated with crime.
3. The company pollutes.
4. The company causes overall employment to drop (e.g., through monopolization or collusion).
5. The company's products lead to too much illness (national healthcare costs increase).
6. The company's products lead to addiction (ties up too much public liquidity, doesn't allow other businesses to grow).
7. The company is an embarrassment (the owner was caught golfing with Satan).

In the broader view, non-monetary things can affect economics. Literally, an owner's/manager's scandalous behavior can drive down stock prices (I'm lookin' at you, Enron!). But just because the government declares something to be "good" or "bad" for the economy, doesn't at all mean it's true. Politicians are constantly trying to sneak their own pet projects/peeves into legislation. So, from a remarkably practical perspective...

*what's good for the economy is that the government says is good for the economy.*

And vice-versa. This should completely resolve your paradoxes, because the process of identifying opportunities for reward and punishment are independent of the process of consumer buying and selling — *as it should be.* The moment you try to get involved with the consumers, this all breaks down very, very quickly.

**Summary**

- Make yourself a list of how you your government can reward businesses for beneficial behavior. Remember that none of these rewards must necessarily have anything to do with money.
- Make yourself a list of how your government can punish businesses for detrimental behavior. Ditto about the money.
- Make yourself a list of how companies can be declared beneficial. Remember, money is only one aspect of being beneficial.
- Make yourself a list of how companies can be declared detrimental. Ditty about the money.
- Send forth your unholy army of inspectors, who are paid to be as narrow minded as possible, and who have at least four levels of management before you get to the supervisors who actually answer to a governing cabinet member. And remember, if someone complains about an inspector or tries to accelerate the process of processing a complaint, such people tend to... well... *disappear.*
- If X>Y, reward. If X<Y, punish. And remember there's nothing wrong about telling the Press about the rewards and punishments. In fact, that, itself, can be rewarding or debilitating.

And if you need inspiration, make a study of [Futurama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurama)'s [Hermes Conrad](https://youtu.be/Q5FsciebhNA) and the bureaucracy of the future!